# reversed legend using guide_legend()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am an absolute beginner in `ggplot2` and practicing to use `guide_legend()` functions. I am not quite sure why `guide_legend()` reverses the order of the legend.

Here's the base example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:3, z = 1:3)
base <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_raster(aes(fill = z))
```

This nicely produces a raster graph.

However, when I add the following line, the order of legend gets reversed. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

```
base + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend())
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts. Is there anyway I can reverse the order?

Thanks

---

**Addition:** I want to add that `reverse = FALSE` by default for guide_legend. I think `reverse=TRUE` will fix it, but I am not understanding the point of resetting the default value. Is there anything wrong that I am doing?

Here's the guide: I am referring to http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html

Here's the pic: [image] This pic is from above website.

Comment: The default guide here is `guide="colourbar"` or `guide=guide_colourbar()`, which gives a continuous color scale. If you use `guide="legend"` or `guide=guide_legend()`, you get a discrete color scale. This is mentioned in the [help for `scale_gradient`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html).

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for your help. I think I am concerned about the order of legend. Base case shows `{3->2->1->0}`. The new case shows `{0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3}` My question isn't about discrete vs. continuous case...

Comment: Yes, but your `base` plot has a continuous color scale by default. The added line converts that to a discrete scale. If that's what you want, then the way to reverse the order is `scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))`

Comment: @eipi10 Isn't my base case continuous? How do I know that the base case use of `z` is discrete and not continuous? Also, I am not sure how `scale_fill_continuous()` would convert this to discrete case.

Comment: You can have ggplot treat it as discrete or continuous, depending on what makes sense for your data. Because your data is numeric, ggplot interprets it as continuous by default. However, if your data can, for example, only take integer values, or if the integers really represent categories or order, rather than a real-number scale, then you might decide a discrete scale makes more sense.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks. Could you please explain your statement "The added line converts that to a discrete scale." above? I am reading http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html Here, Wickham has used continuous scale with 'guide_legend()' and the order didn't change. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've added an answer to explain. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base plot has a continuous color scale, which you can see in the legend:

```
base <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_raster(aes(fill = z))
```

[image]

This converts it to a discrete color scale, because setting `guide="legend"` or `guide=guide_legend()` creates a discrete scale (this is [documented in the help](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient.html)):

```
base + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

For a continuous color scale, you could use the code below, but it's not necessary because that's already what ggplot does by default when the color variable is continuous (as shown in your `base` plot):

```
base + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_colourbar())
```

Keep discrete color scale, but reverse order so that highest value is on top. I've also set the breaks so that only 3 colors are displayed in the legend:

```
base + scale_fill_continuous(breaks=1:3, guide=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** To address the long comment thread, here are the three plots from [the ggplot help for `guide_legend`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html). But note that the first one is not actually displayed on the ggplot help page; only the code is shown.

```
df <- reshape2::melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2"))

p1 = ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
p2 = p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = "legend")
p3 = p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. My query is inspired by http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html If you see this, Wickham has a continuous `df$value`, and he uses the same function as I did. However, the order doesn't get reversed. Thoughts?

Comment: The order is reversed in the help document you linked to. In the first plot `p1`, the legend is a continuous color scale with the highest value on top. Then, when `scale_fill_continuous(guide = "legend")` is added, the color scale becomes discrete with the lowest value on top. When a variable is treated as discrete (i.e., categorical), the legend is ordered alphabetically from lowest to highest. For example, if you add `df$w=c("B","C","A")` and do `fill=w`, you'll notice that you get a discrete legend with "A" on top.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure. I have posted the image from the website. I don't see the two legends reversed. I believe there is a big disconnect in what I am seeing and what you are seeing...Could you please double-check?

Comment: The help page does not include an image of the original plot. The code for that plot is `p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))`. Run it and see what you get. The two plots you posted were created with two code snippets that each do exactly the same thing: `p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = "legend")` and `p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend())`. Both of these convert the legend from continuous to discrete and reverse the order.

Comment: thanks so much for patiently answering my questions. Here's the code (from the website) that I ran `df <- reshape2::melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2"))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
p2 <- p1 + geom_point(aes(size = value))
# Basic form
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = "legend")` I am not sure where the disconnect is but I am getting exactly the same graphs as they are on the website. I cleared the environment and ran the query afresh before posting this, and still got the same graph.

Comment: The plot that results from `p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))` is not displayed on the web site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughts. You've been extremely patient and helpful. Did you try running the code that is posted on the website and the one I included above ? I'm curious --what output did you get?