# Order levels of a factor in a guide and on the axis of a flipped barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

Hi there: Is there a way to modify the plot below so that the factor 'C' is displayed on top? i.e. I'd like the order of the factors on the (flipped) y-axis to mirror the order of them displayed in the legend.

```
var1<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), replace=T, size=100)
var2<-sample(c('apples', 'bananas'), replace=T, size=100)
var3<-rnorm(100, mean=100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

df %>% 
  mutate(var1=fct_reorder(var1, var3, mean)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(y=var1, x=var3, fill=var1))+facet_wrap(~var2)+geom_col()+scale_fill_grey()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reversed legend using guide\_legend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156114/reversed-legend-using-guide-legend)

Comment: Try with `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
mutate(var1=fct_reorder(var1, var3, mean)) %>% 
ggplot(., aes(y=var1, x=var3, fill=var1)) + 
facet_wrap(~var2)+
geom_col()+
scale_fill_grey() +
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[image]